# App and Terminal Isolation / Sandboxing

Tags: terminal, applications, security, sandbox

Not often I need to do something very unique and specific on my m1 (apple silicon) macbook air. Something like:

- I'll be interested in video game emulation, and need very specific controller support, and be downloading apps to run games.
- I'll need to convert or edit videos, and download a bunch of tools to get what I need to do done.
- I'll be interested in some obscure new terminal-based command for a programming language I found trending.
- Software for specific micro-controllers / burners

In all of these cases, there's a novel and new software I'm installing on my system, and generally I have to ***trust*** that none of this code is malicious, installs something that runs in the background, tracks my keyboard, or gets access to my personal files.

1. Is this a reasonable fear?
2. Is there a way to run this code in isolation from the rest of my system?

Ideally I could spin up some kind of sandbox, download the apps or terminal commands run what I need and possibly delete the sandbox as if it never existed. Ideally there's no hit to performance, and it's not cumbersome to use. I thought about using different mac profiles, but I know some apps install on a whole disk, and anything installed by the admin has admin access no?

Comment: As long as you avoid pirated software and software that purports to do something illegal, your chances of encountering malware are low. But if you're suspicious, you can run it in a virtual machine using one of the virtualization apps in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something called `sandbox-exec` which accepts a "seat-belt" file `.sb` which is a set of permissions regarding what the app or script can access.

Where I found out about this: https://davd.io/os-x-run-any-command-in-a-sandbox

Here's an example:

```sh
sandbox-exec -f no-network.sb /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC
```

Some example seat-belt files:

- https://github.com/s7ephen/OSX-Sandbox--Seatbelt--Profiles?tab=readme-ov-file
- https://github.com/pansen/macos-sandbox-profiles

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61880980/340688